# Pokemon Artwork download copyright question

Tags: copyright

Okay so can i show direct downloaded Pokemon Artwork from http://www.pokemon.co.jp/ex/usum/
like the downloaded picture in a youtube video with that as the only thing and make a download for all the artwork in the decs ?

Comment: [Read the basics. No.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/i-have-a-question-about-copyright-what-should-i-read-before-i-ask-it)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Just because the artwork is available for free on the internet doesn't allow you to copy it and put it into a video

Long answer: Depends if your video falls under fair use, such as if it was a review on the images.